# Excel: How do I return the header/title of a column that contains data in each row?

Tags: excel-formula

For each row in column V I'm trying to show which "type" of Geo-Targeting that row is using. In the screenshot I'm just showing what I'd want to return in each row for column V. Each row will only contain data in ONE of columns R through U and that's the column I want to identfy.
[image]

not even sure where to start

Answer (score 0):

```
=LET(
     range,S1:V8,
           header, TAKE(range,1),
           data,   DROP(range,1),
IFS(INDEX(data,,1)<>"",INDEX(header,,1),
    INDEX(data,,2)<>"",INDEX(header,,2),
    INDEX(data,,3)<>"",INDEX(header,,3),
    INDEX(data,,4)<>"",INDEX(header,,4)))
```